# How do I install Nix packages on a Nixos docker image?

Tags: docker, nixos

Short version: I need to include the `file` utility on a Docker image. Source and target environments are both NixOS. How do I define the docker image so that another executable can invoke it, or any other prepackaged executable?

Longer version: I've been successfully building a docker image, where I copy a precompiled executable into place. That executable now needs to invoke the `file` utility to identify the mime-type of various files, and that's where I'm stuck.

Using `buildInputs` the way I do in `shell.nix` doesn't have the desired effect. Could somebody point me to the clues I need?

My `docker.nix` is as follows:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

let
    foobar_deriv = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
        name = "foobar";
        builder = "${bash}/bin/bash";
        args = [ ./nix-builder.sh ];
        inherit coreutils openssl libyaml;
        system = builtins.currentSystem;
        schemapath = ../../schemas;
        foobarpath = ./foobar;

        buildInputs = [
            pkgs.bash
            pkgs.file
        ];
        env = buildEnv {
            name = name;
            paths = buildInputs;
        };

    };

    ld_path = stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath [
        pkgs.openssl
        pkgs.libyaml
    ];

    entrypoint = writeScript "entrypoint.sh" ''
    #!${stdenv.shell}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ld_path}
    exec $@
    '';

in
pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
    name = "myaccount/foobar";
    tag = "0.3.0a11";
    created = "now";

    contents = foobar_deriv;

    config = {
        Cmd = [ "foobar" ];
        Entrypoint = [ entrypoint ];
        ExposedPorts = {
            "4949/tcp" = {};
        };
        WorkingDir = "/";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer was simpler than I expected: if you define `contents` as a list instead of an atom, the derivations are combined into the final image.

For this specific case, the solution was to change

```
contents = foobar_deriv;
```

to

```
contents = [ foobar_deriv file ];
```

In practice, I added more utilities so I can poke around as necessary, so it became

```
contents = [ foobar_deriv file bash which coreutils ];
```